# If you had the time and inclination to create a programming language, what characteristics would it have?

Tags: python, c++

Just curious.  If you had the time and inclination to create a programming language, what characteristics would it have?

One language I would like to see would borrow as much from the syntax of Python as possible but compile to machine code that runs as fast as C or C++.

Comment: Have you seen Go? http://golang.org or Psyco? http://psyco.sourceforge.net/

Comment: make it a community wiki please

Comment: i didn't mean for it to be argumentative. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mix of COBOL and XML, for the lulz

```
<program>
    <data>
        <const>
            <name>myStr</name>
            <value><[CDATA[Hello, World!]]></value>
        </const>
    </data>
    <sub>
        <name>main</name>
        <params />
        <return />
        <code>
            <call>
                <name>writeline</name>
                <params>
                    <var>myStr</var>
                </params>
                <giving />
            </call>
        </code>
    </sub>
    <meta>
        <entrypoint>main</entrypoint>
    </meta>
</program>
```

Comment: See the hello world I added ;)

Comment: Oh, of course. It's even enterprise-enabled already!

Answer (score 5):

I would limit my language to one statement:

```
Solve my problem.
```

Maybe i'd add one modifier though, in case its urgent:

```
Solve my problem, please.
```

Comment: ... sorry, but i couldn't resist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Programmer would be able to explicitly set the types of vars. And of the arguments in a cool way, like

   ```
   (string str, array(int)|int someint_or_more, any some_strange_argument)
   ```

   something like this :)
2. Programmer would be able to use lambdas, closures, etc at least as in JS
3. It would have protytipes-based OOP (like in JS)
4. Blocks (if { ... }, etc) would act like a closures!
5. It would have a special keyword to define a function which return constant value (if arguments haven't been changed) so It can be cached by compiler/interpreter without any programmers thought about it. It would be very useful, you would be able to use recursion for almost anything and don't really suck with perfomance!

Answer (score 0):

It should be fast and lightweight (not like the .NET Framework), but you should still be able to create fully functional and flexible GUI apps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple block for defining things that can run in parallel, so if I write:

```
parallel{
  do_x();
  do_y();
}
something_else();
```

do_x() and do_y() would be executed in parallel, but something_else() would only be run after both of them complete.

Comment: I wrote a scripting language like this a while back.  I called it psh or "pourne shell" as a bourne shell with parallel for loops.  It worked wonderfully for me.  I should clean up the page I had for it and put the repo up somewhere.

Comment: I just wish I could do this in C++ or Java. It's not like it's *hard* to write things to execute in parellel, it just takes way more effort than it should for something this simple.

Comment: You can do it in C++ - write your function template `parallel()` that takes e.g. multiple `boost::function` as arguments.

Comment: I wrote something like this in the early 90's for VAX/VMS. We had a project whose build times ran about 6 or 7 hours, and so I wrote a processor that would spread this across 8 or 9 uVAXes, based on `!FORK` and `!JOIN` comments in the build script - cut the build down to about an hour.